# How to get force constants in internal coordinates in Gaussian?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I have tried quite a few different ways to get Gaussian to print the force constants in internal coordinates. If the size of the molecule is small then it prints both the internal hessian and Cartesian hessian in the log file on using `Iop(7/32=5)`, it outputs only the Cartesian hessian without the `Iop` command. But if the size of the molecule is large then it stops printing the hessian in the `.log` file. Though the Cartesian hessian is always printed in the checkpoint file. How do I get the internal hessian? I am also using `#p` to get Gaussian to write everything in the log file.

Comment: I haven't attempted to validate this post yet, but it is suggested in the following link that if you include #p freq=intmodes, it should return the internal hessian under "Internal force constants" in the log file. https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_extract_the_Hessian_from_Gaussian

Comment: I have tried that, you do get the internal modes in the log file if the molecule is small. But for bigger molecules it stops printing either the cartesian or the internal hessian in the log file. Though the cartesian hessian can be found in the checkpoint file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `freq=intmodes` and use the command

```
formchk -3 xxxx.chk xxxx.fchk
```

to convert the binary checkpoint file to a formatted checkpoint file, which consists of text. The `-3` requests the version 3 of formatted checkpoint files, which support all features of Gaussian 09 and 16.

Source: [Ruixing Wang's answer on Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_get_force_constants_in_internal_coordinates_in_Gaussian.), where I asked the same question.